# How to send literal form of special key sequences with --remote-send

Tags: clientserver

I am using vim --remote-send. As per [the documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/remote.html#--remote-send) It automatically expands "special" key signifiers, so that e.g. `vim --remote-send "<C-t>"` simulates pressing ctrl-t. I would like to send the literal key sequence `<`,`C`,`-`,`t`,`>`, but vim's documentation offers no clues. I have tried `vim --remote-send '\<C-t>'` but this just does a literal backslash followed by ctrl-t. How can I escape special sequences?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In any context where a "keycode" is expected, use `<lt>` to represent a literal `<`.

```
vim --remote-send "<lt>C-t>"
```

See also [:help keycodes](https://neovim.io/doc/user/intro.html#keycodes).